# Getting a Thread with its latest Post within the same object, latest() creates a huge overhead

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have this in my model called Thread.php:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function latestPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->latest('id');
}
```

I have a page which displays all threads with their latest post. To do so, I do something like

`all_threads = Thread::with('latestPost')->get();`

It does this query:

```
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`thread_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10') order by `id` desc
```

It works, but `latestPost()` is grabbing all posts in the table, for each thread, and then returning the latest one. This is making thousands of unnecessary objects and the overhead is already high.

The ideal would be to just take the latest `Post` record, but I'm not sure how to do it with Eloquent.

I've tried the following:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1);
// or
return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->latest('id')->take(1);
```

But then only the last Thread object comes with a latestPost record. How can I optimize this query while still using Eloquent?

Thanks

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question as well; but for now theoretically if you don't preload the relationship it would take less resources (assuming you're listing 20 Threads you would have 21 queries only)

Comment: Yeah, I would guess that using the ORM for this kind of operations causes an unintentional explosion of the number of queries. This is often called the N+1 problem. See [The N+1 Problem](https://laracasts.com/lessons/eager-loading) on Laracasts

Answer (score 1):

You could try throwing a `group by` on the `thread_id` to limit the records returned to 1 per thread.

Using the `posts` relationship as an example:

```
$threads = Thread::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
    $q->groupBy('thread_id');
})->get();
```

Query Log for the eager loading:

```
"select * from "posts" where "posts"."thread_id" in (?) group by "thread_id""
```

If you run that Query via `DB::select` it should only be returning 1 record per `thread_id`. Which means it doesn't have to hydrate unneeded models to just match 1 up per parent as it will only have 1 max per parent to start with.